# Popup warning that blob cannot be opened because of browser settings when generating data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, lightning-experience, blob, cors, csp

When generating a CSV file with Javascript, and trying to make the file available for download locally, using the snippet below:

```js
const blobToBase64 = (blob) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        reader.onloadend = () => {
            resolve(reader.result);
        };
    });
};
```

The page works fine in Classic. But in Lightning Experience I get this annoying popup saying that because of browser settings it needs permission to access the URL. When I click "open" anyway, nothing happens (expected file download, like in Classic, instead).

The URL is different from the one I see on the browser:

| Section | URL |
| --- | --- |
| Browser search bar | https://company--sandboxname.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/DynamicExportUtilityPage |
| Popup warning | https://company--sandboxname--c.sandbox.vf.force.com |

I've added the popup warning URL to CSP and CORS, but nothing happens. The browser allows popups from the address too.

Would it be possible to make this work?